# How to use jQuery with webpack-encore in a Symfony project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, webpack-encore

I have a problem with webpack-encore and jQuery.
I have a custom.js file with this code:

```
import "../css/custom.css";

var $ = require("jquery");

global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

And in the twig file i have this code:

```
<script src="{{asset('build/js/custom.js')}}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        alert("1");
    })
</script>
```

The path to custom.js passed as argument is correct.

When I compile with `yarn run encore dev` jQuery module is not inside the generated file for `custom.js` but is in another file named `0.b9e94bd1.js`.

The problem is that it gives me the error `$ is not defined`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does custom.js refer to the `0.b9...` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I changed asset function inside the twig with encore_entry_script_tags, now jQuery and $ are defined.

Comment: none of those methods not working. fresh symfony 5.4 with latest encore. and just a simple template with few  resources. Encore is a Cannon on the FLY.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to uncomment this line in webpack.config.js

```
     // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()
```

see https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore/autoprovide-jquery-modules

Answer (score 0):

If you put a

```
console.log('hello world');
```

in the custom.js of your example (normally this would be app.js), you will see that app.js is loaded after the other scripts, so they do not have access to the global jQuery variable.

To fix this, set defer to false in config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml

```
webpack_encore:
    script_attributes:
        defer: false
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-applications.html